# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to fill this array with pictures(png) and I got an error.. any suggestions?

```
//body part images
private ImageView[] bodyParts;


bodyParts = new ImageView[numParts];
bodyParts[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1);
bodyParts[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage2);
bodyParts[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage3);
bodyParts[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage4);
bodyParts[4].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage5);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: **numParts = 5**

Comment: You haven't assigned a value to any of your `bodyParts` elements.

Comment: ***Off Topic:*** The **Android-studio** shouldnt be a tag in your post  sinse you dont talk about it.

Answer (score 1):

This error appeared because there is no imageview in the array, you used the method setImageResource() on a null object
, the array bodyParts don't contains any imageview